# How to insert a variable in a string that is repeated multiple times in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write code efficiently that does something like this:

```
if (str == "Sunday"):
   return "Today is Sunday. Have a good day."
```

or

```
if (str == "Monday")
  return "Today is Saturday. Have a good day."
```

etc..

Is there a way to set the standard string with a variable {} and then assign the variable later on the script - without having to repeat the string 7 times?

Comment: Tried `.format()`?

Comment: I find your question a little bit unclear, but maybe https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings could help you here!?

Comment: You would have to test this, but I believe you could use `f-strings` for this… example… `def daily_greet(day): return f”Today is {day}. Have a good day.”`

Comment: Don't name your variables or parameters `str`, that's shadowing the built-in `str` type - but since you have, you're looking for `return f'Today is {str}. Have a good day.'` (note the 'f')

Comment: `return` is a keyword used only in functions/methods, not in "if" statements. Please don't name variables with reserved words/standard type names/standard functions like `str`

Answer (score 0):

`str` conflicts with Python's own builtin `str` function, so I will assume you named the input `day` instead.

You can do this in several ways:

```
# concatenate
return "Today is " + day + ". Have a good day"

# f-string
return f"Today is {day}. Have a good day"

# format method (f-string is just alternate syntax for this)
return "Today is {}. Have a good day".format(day)
```

The common name for this is "string interpolation", so you can search for that to learn more.